# Erro na compilação?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Que erro é esse quando mando compilar minha aplicação?

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'BlankPage1' does not contain a definition for 'listView_SelectionChanged' and no extension method 'listView_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'BlankPage1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Alerta  C:\Users\ novo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Alerta\Alerta\BlankPage1.xaml  16  Active

---

> C:\Users\ novo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Alerta\Alerta\BlankPage1.xaml(16,105,16,130): error CS1061: 'BlankPage1' does not contain a definition for 'listView_SelectionChanged' and no extension method 'listView_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'BlankPage1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: clica duas vezes no erro .. e vai na linha que esta sublinhada de vermelho e remove ela...

Comment: Você deve ter excluído o evento `SelectionChanged` de `listView`, correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já foi dito nos comentários, você provavelmente removeu o método `private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`

**Duas soluções:**

1)Remover referência

Vá na `BlankPage1` e procure a  `listview` que está na linha 16 e remove a referência do evento `SelectionChanged`.

2)Adicionar referencia

Vá no arquivo BlankPage1.xaml.cs e adicione o seguinte método:

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO:Adicione o seu código aqui
}
```